# Firebase Functions: Call function in Project A from project B

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing two different Angular firebase app. Both projects has own firebase functions, till here everything is cool.
Now I have a schedulded function in project A which should call an function from project B (other function server url). Sounds easy but in firebase functions I can't use an httpclient like in the Angular code:

```
return this.http.post(this.API_URL_SENDMAIL(), model, { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise().then(
  (res: any) => {
    let resultObj = JSON.parse(res);
    return resultObj;
  }
);
```

If I have this code in functions everything will be okay, but I havent :/
Can anyone help me to build the code above in a firebase function project

I've tried it with fetch() and axios, but nothing worked for me :/

Answer (score 0):

You can very well trigger an HTTPS request from a Cloud Function by using, for example, the axios library.

So in project A, use axios in your Cloud Function and in project B use an HTTPS Cloud Function which will be called by the Project A Cloud Function.

You'll find several examples on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cloud%20Functions%20axios) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3371862%20axios). If you encounter specific problems, please update your question with your code and debugging details.

Comment: Hello @YannicMair, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?